# Confidence interval of proportion of a proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, proportion

Let's say we have $N$ users. Some of them could be hackers and some not.

Only for a random $p_u$ percent (e.g. 1%) of users have we actually investigated manually to know which ones are hackers and which ones are not hackers (let's say $p_h$ of them are hackers).

The whole population is constantly using our website. So we get network packets as people navigate the site.

**We want to know what is the overall proportion of network packets that are from hackers?**

However, since the total number of packets, $M$, is huge, we can only sample a portion, $N$, of all network packets for analysis (let's say $p_p = \frac{N}{M}=5\%$ of all network packets are being stored for analysis). So we store $N=Mp_n$ packets.

Among those $N=Mp_n$ network packets that we have stored, we can count how many of them come from our list of known hackers ($n_h$), then divide that by $N$ and de-bias it by multiplying with $\frac{1}{p_u}$.

So the expected value of our random variable of interest = $\frac{n_h}{Np_u}=\frac{n_h}{Mp_np_u}$

**My question is**: what is the *confidence interval* of above variable of interest?

Comment: The variable $n_h$ that you measure/count (and from which you obtain your final quantity by some scaling with constants) is from an over-dispersed binomial distribution. 

For a *fixed* set of hackers the counting of the proportion of hackerpackets in a sample of packets is binomial distributed. But your set of hackers is not fixed. So the variable $n_h$ that you obtain (and from which you obtain your final quantity by some scaling with constants) is an over-dispersed binomial distribution.

Comment: You could approximate this with a beta-binomial distribution where a beta-distribution is used to model the (variable) probability-parameter of the binomial distribution, and in this you can incorporate the variation among hackers (which you can fit with your sample) and the variation due to your (variable) sampling of the number of known hackers.

Possibly there might be more advanced techniques or software tools that do this multilevel modeling.

Comment: You may improve your result (and simplify analysis) by including the number of packets from known not-hackers.